# Count selected radio button using mat-radio-button in angular 8

Tags: angular

I want to count how many radio button checked using mat-radio-button in angular 8.

app.component.html:

```html
<form id="formData" [formGroup]="Form">
    <div class="flight-center" *ngFor="let airlinenameid of airlineNameID | searchfilter:value">
        <div class="col-3">
            <p>FlightCenter</p>
            <mat-radio-group [(ngModel)]="FlightName" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" (ngModelChange)="countRadio($event)">
                <mat-radio-button *ngFor="let flightcenter of airlinenameid.flightCenter"
                    [value]="flightcenter.value" ngDefaultControl name="flightDate">{{flightcenter.name}}
                </mat-radio-button>
            </mat-radio-group>
        </div>
        <div class="col-3">
            <p>HelloWord</p>
            <mat-radio-group [(ngModel)]="HelloWorldName" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">
                <mat-radio-button (change)="countRadio($event.target)" *ngFor="let helloword of airlinenameid.HelloWord"
                    [value]="helloword.value">{{helloword.name}}
                </mat-radio-button>
            </mat-radio-group>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

app.component.ts:

```js
countRadio(event: any[]){
    this.airlineNameID.forEach(value => {
        value.flightCenter.forEach(item => {
            if(item['checked']){
                this.counterFlight = this.counterFlight + 1;
            }
        });
        value.HelloWord.forEach(item => {
            if(item['checked']){
                this.counterFlight = this.counterFlight + 1;
            }
        });
    });   
    
    alert(event);
    
}
```

But the problem is I am not getting selected radio button count while using checkboxes it works fine.

Comment: You're not enumerating the `mat-radio-button` elements, you're enumerating the collection they're bound to. The items in `flightCenter` don't have a `checked` property, they have a `value` property. Instead of `if (item['checked'])`, use `if (item.value)`.

Comment: Unless the items in `flightCenter` *do* have a `checked` property, in which case you should update your template to bind to the correct field. Instead of `[value]="flightcenter.value"`, use `[value]="flightcenter.checked"`.

Comment: @DM is there any link apart from javascript/jquery which describe how to get count of number of radio button checked in Angular 8.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Only one button in a radio group can be checked at a time.

Comment: There are are multiple mat-radio-group that i mention above, example:- RadioA having multiple radio buttons and RadioB having multiple radio buttons. If i check any RadioA data it will show "1 data checked". If i check any RadioB data it will increment count. I need a count of checked radio buttons by selecting multiple different mat-radio-group. I need a count of radio button checked in angular 8.